# Vue - ignore watcher in first specific initialization

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-mixin

I have use case where I can't move on and I will appreciate your help. In my vue component I have watcher for model "foo"'s properties `aaa`and `bbb` like this:

```
watch: {
   'foo.aaa': function () {
       this.foo.bbb = null;
       this.callRest();
    },
   'foo.bbb': function () {
       this.callRest();
    },
}
```

there are multiple select inputs and select with model `foo.bbb` depends on select with model `foo.aaa` so I need set `bbb` to null when `aaa` changed.

Now I need solve case where I modify `foo` object and set its properties from mixin's `created` method. In that case when I change it from mixin I need ignore watcher's because it always null `bbb` property. Can you tell me how to solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using oldVal to determine whether the watcher is in the first specific initialization or not. Maybe it will look like this...

```
'foo.aaa': function (newVal, oldVal) {
   if(oldVal) {
     // not in first specific initialization 
     this.foo.bbb = null;
     this.callRest();
   } else {
     // in first specific initialization 
   }
},
```

Hopefully, I don't misunderstood your question.

Comment: oldValue won't be undefined in the first try as it is an empty object proxy, I don't think this answer is valid anymore

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should manage the state of *how* the object is being manipulated. For example, create a boolean data value named something like `editedFromMixin`, which defaults to `false`.

When changing values from the `created` method of your mixin, update `editedFromMixin` to `true`.

Then, in your watchers, check if `editedFromMixin` is false before setting `foo.bbb` to `null`. And finally, also in your mixin, end by flipping `editedFromMixin` back to the default `false`.

The effect is changes from the mixin will set the flag that prevents your watchers from making the undesired changes – but only once per iteration of updates.